# Customize Salesforce1 List Views

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

In default list views, the "link" to click on a record is the record's ID. This annoying limitation is avoided with a formula field which generates a hyperlink which has a more readable label. My issue is that these hyperlinks do not render correctly in Salesforce1 (for iOS). In the iOS app, instead of generating, for example, a tappable "John Doe" in the list view, we'll see (a href="/a00......" target="_self"....)  etc. This is perfect for the website, but the mobile app can't handle it. What is a way to hide this? Two options I can think of are 1. custom list views for users on mobile, or 2. formula fields that somehow check if the user is on mobile. 
Is either of these possible? 
Below is the offensive image.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue and has been successfully reproduced by Salesforce support as confirmed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46077/salesforce1-and-hyperlink-showing-raw-html).

As for workarounds, I think "formula fields that somehow check if the user is on mobile" is going to be quiet difficult so I'd advise on creating a custom list view for mobile. Depending on which HTML5/ responsive CSS framework, there are components available for listview which you can parameterise as per your requirements.

Comment: Custom mobile list views sound great, thanks. Could you direct me to documentation that describes how to effect this? Certain Salesforce docs ask you to go to a section called "Mobile Configuration", but I don't see this in the most recent Salesforce implementation. By the way -- developing for Salesforce1, iOS.